# nginx localhost servername work fine on chrome but not on firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, nginx, localhost

I just installed and config `nginx` in my localhost server (`ubuntu`) and set my server names as `example.dev` in `sites-available` and `sites-enabled`.

The problem is my example sites work fine in `chrome` but not working on `firefox`.
I can not figure out what's the problem.

Comment: Browsers interpret localhost a little differently, can you post your config?

Comment: First of all, could you post curl output of your localhost `curl http://127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's outdated but it works for me in Firefox, open Preferences -> Advanced -> Network open Settings and check manual proxy config and set proxy HTTP 127.0.0.1 and port 80

But use this only when you develop site, beacuse other sites probably will don't working